# Examples of automorphic representations to keep in mind

Tags: big-list, automorphic-forms, examples, counterexamples

I have recently started studying the automorphic science and find it somewhat hard to form intuition. Can we have a list of examples of automorphic representations that you usually use to test a new idea, or that are counterexamples to a statement that might look reasonable to a beginner but is actually false? Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666113/251240) question.

Comment: GL(1), GL(2) and endoscopic lifts, like Saito-Kurokawa.  The latter examples disproved the original generalized Ramanujan conjecture.